# Implementing search in plain UITableview with alphabetical headers

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am trying to implement the headers with alphabetical order and implementing search on it. But not showing the all data, showing header for one alphabet only and showing it's values only. and in search also not showing values except that one alphabet. Below is the code i used.

```
-(void)getData
{
NSLog(@"get data:%@", self.mGetDataDict);

NSLog(@"count:%d", [self.mGetDataDict count]);

NSString *getStatus = [self.mGetDataDict valueForKey:@"status"];
NSArray *dictAllKeys = [[NSArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *getAllDict = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSLog(@"getfinalStatus----------%@",getStatus);

if([getStatus  isEqual:[NSNumber numberWithBool:0]])
{
    NSLog(@"status:%@", getStatus);
}
else
{
    dictAllKeys = [self.mGetDataDict allKeys];
    for(int i=1; i<=[dictAllKeys count]; i++)
    {
        getAllDict = [self.mGetDataDict valueForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]];
        [self.mArrName addObject:[getAllDict valueForKey:@"name"]];
        [self.mArrPImg addObject:[getAllDict valueForKey:@"profileImage"]];
        if([seatMapStatus isEqualToString:@"yes"])
        {
        [self.mArrIng addObject:[getAllDict valueForKey:@"ing"]];
        }

        stateIndex = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (int i=0; i<[self.mArrName count]-1; i++){
            //---get the first char of each state---
            char alphabet = [[self.mArrName objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
            NSString *uniChar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", alphabet];

            //---add each letter to the index array---
            if (![stateIndex containsObject:uniChar])
            {
                [stateIndex addObject:uniChar];
            }
        }
    }
}
 NSLog(@"index:%@", stateIndex);
NSLog(@"name:%@", self.mArrName);

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
return 60;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return [stateIndex count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@"copy arr:%d", [copyArr count]);
if(searching)
{
    NSString *alphabet = [stateIndex objectAtIndex:section];

//---get all states beginning with the letter---
NSPredicate *predicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
NSArray *states = [copyArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

//---return the number of states beginning with the letter---
return [states count];
   // return [copyArr count];
}
else{
    NSString *alphabet = [stateIndex objectAtIndex:section];

//---get all states beginning with the letter---
NSPredicate *predicate =
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
NSArray *states = [self.mArrName filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

//---return the number of states beginning with the letter---
return [states count];

}
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section        {

return [stateIndex objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString*)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
return index;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell;
cell = [self.mEventMemTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
else{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

NSString *imageUrlString = [self.mArrPImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

asyncImageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 5, 50, 45)];
[asyncImageView loadImageFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:asyncImageView];

UILabel *lblName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 15, 150, 30)];
if([copyArr count] >0)
{
    //---get the letter in the current section---
    NSString *alphabet = [stateIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    //---get all states beginning with the letter---
    NSPredicate *predicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    NSArray *states = [copyArr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if ([states count]>0) {
        //---extract the relevant state from the states object---
        //NSString *cellValue = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       // cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    lblName.text = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
}
else{
    //---get the letter in the current section---
    NSString *alphabet = [stateIndex objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    //---get all states beginning with the letter---
    NSPredicate *predicate =
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];

    NSArray *states = [self.mArrName filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    if ([states count]>0) {
        //---extract the relevant state from the states object---
        //NSString *cellValue = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       // cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    lblName.text = [states objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
}
[cell addSubview:lblName];

return cell;
}

- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {

searching = YES;
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

//Remove all objects first.
[copyArr removeAllObjects];

if([searchText length]) {

    searching = YES;
    //letUserSelectRow = YES;
    //self.tableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [self searchTableView];
}
else {
    searching = NO;
}
[self.mEventMemTableView reloadData];
}

- (void) searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar {
[self.mSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
[self searchTableView];
}

- (void) searchTableView {

NSString *searchText = self.mSearchBar.text;
NSMutableArray *searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *sTemp in self.mArrName)
{
    NSRange titleResultsRange = [sTemp rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (titleResultsRange.length)
        [copyArr addObject:sTemp];
}
searchArray = nil;

}
```

Please guide for the above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Listings/3_SimpleIndexedTableView_Classes_RootViewController_m.html

UILocalizedIndexedCollation class

and

configureSections method

thats a reference for you, dig into it and everything will be clean and ok :)

Do the section headers at first (before search)